Stripe, invalid csrf token
I am developing a project using Stripe API and Node.js, integrated with Handlebars. I'm new to Node.js and Handlebars. I have a problem, that states invalide csrf token at
csrf (/Users/Ahmadzai/Desktop/stripe_customer/node_modules/csurf/index.js:112:19) . I have tried many ways but it did'nt work for me. I would be pleased if someone is able to answer the question. Here is my code.
const express = require('express');
const csurf = require('csurf');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const session = require('express-session'); 
const app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const csrfProtection = csurf({ cookie: true });
app.use(csrfProtection);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.csrfToken = req.csrfToken(); // Get CSRF token
    console.log("Generated CSRF Token:", res.locals.csrfToken); // Log generated token
    next();
});

app.post('/cancel-subscription/:subscriptionId', async (req, res) => {
    const { subscriptionId } = req.params; 
    
    try {
        await stripe.subscriptions.del(subscriptionId);
        await db.query(
            'UPDATE customers SET subscription_id = NULL, active_abonnement = FALSE WHERE subscription_id = ?',
            [subscriptionId]
        );
        console.log('Subscription canceled.');
        res.render('subscriptions', { message: 'Subscription canceled successfully!' }); 
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error canceling subscription:', error);
        res.render('subscriptions', { message: 'Failed to cancel subscription. Please try again.' }); 
    }
});

 <form class="form" method="POST" action="/cancel-subscription/{{subscriptionId}}">
     <div class="mb-3">
         <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{csrfToken}}">
         <input type="hidden" name="subscriptionId" value="{{this.id}}"> 
<!-- Hidden field for subscription ID -->
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-md" value="Cancel">Cancel Subscription</button>
</div>
</form>

